# Compact objects and BH equations of state

Tags: thermodynamics, black-holes, quantum-states

White dwarfs and neutron stars do have equations of state (we know then basically from quantum mechanics). Does a black hole have an equation of state?

Answer (score 1):

The closest thing is [the first law of black hole thermodynamics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_hole_thermodynamics#The_first_law):
$$
dE = \frac{\kappa}{8\pi}\,dA + \Omega\,dJ + \Phi\,dQ,
$$
where $E$ is the black hole energy (mass) (in units $c=G=1$), $\kappa$ is the black hole's surface gravity,  $A$ is the horizon area, $\Omega $ is the angular velocity, $ J$ is the angular momentum, $\Phi $ is the electrostatic potential and $Q$ is the electric charge.